# Select grouped random rows, change value in one column

Tags: r, dplyr

For my study design I need to select a total of 12 rows from each group (10 groups) and change the value of one column from 0 to 1.
How would I go about this? I tried the sample_n already, but then it only gives me the randomly selected rows, not the entire dataset.

```
test <- test %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(
  change_value = sample_n(12) 
) %>% ungroup()
```

Sorry I am stuck after this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps you want `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% sample_n(5) %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = sample(0:1, size = n(), replace = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is not very clear.

**case-1** when you want to select 12 random rows from each group, change value of one column and return entire dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2021)
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width = ifelse(sample(1:n(), n()) <= 12, 1, Sepal.Width)) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         1            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           1            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         1            1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         1            1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ... with 140 more rows
```